# Dropzone JS и flask: паралельная загузка чанков

Tags: python, flask, upload, dropzone

Я пытаюсь загружать файл с помощью dropzone.js и бекендом на flask. Конфигурация dropzon:

```
<form method="POST" action='/process_chunk' class="dropzone dz-clickable"
     id="dropper" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>

<script type="application/javascript">
   Dropzone.options.dropper = {
       {# https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/wikis/faq#chunked-uploads #}
       paramName: 'file',
       acceptedFiles: '.csv',
       chunking: true,
       forceChunking: true,
       chunkSize: 100000, // bytes
       parallelChunkUploads: true,
       maxFilesize: 1025, // megabytes
</script>
```

и колбек-функция на бекенде, которая обрабатывает чанки:

```
@app.route('/process_chunk', methods=['POST'])
def process_chunk():
    current_chunk = int(request.form['dzchunkindex'])

    file = request.files['file']
    save_path = os.path.join(app.config['DATA_DIR'], file.filename)

    try:
        with open(save_path, 'ab+') as f:
            # Goto the offset, aka after the chunks we already wrote
            f.seek(int(request.form['dzchunkbyteoffset']))
            f.write(file.stream.read())
    except OSError:
        # log.exception will include the traceback so we can see what's wrong
        log.exception('Could not write to file')
        return make_response(("Couldn't write the file to disk", 500))

    total_chunks = int(request.form['dztotalchunkcount'])

    if current_chunk + 1 == total_chunks:
        # This was the last chunk, the file should be complete and the size we expect
        if os.path.getsize(save_path) != int(request.form['dztotalfilesize']):
            log.error(f"File {file.filename} was completed, "
                      f"but has a size mismatch."
                      f"Was {os.path.getsize(save_path)} but we"
                      f" expected {request.form['dztotalfilesize']} ")
            return make_response(('Size mismatch', 500))
        else:
            log.info(f'File {file.filename} has been uploaded successfully')
    else:
        log.debug(f'Chunk {current_chunk + 1} of {total_chunks} '
                  f'for file {file.filename} complete')

    return make_response(("Chunk upload successful", 200))
```

Все работает замечательно, если установить `parallelChunkUploads` в false. Чанки загружаются последовательно один за другим, и загруженный файл выглядит в точности, как исходный. Для примера, я беру маленький файл (409 байт) и устанавливаю размер чанка в 50 байт:

[image: serial chunk upload].

Когда я устанавливаю `parallelChunkUploads` в true, чанки загружаются параллельно:

[image: parallel chunk upload]

Но данные в загруженном файле полностью перепутаны

**original file**

```
cod,char,xx
01,aaaa,xx
02,bbbb,xx
03,cccc,xx
04,dddd,xx
05,eeee,xx
06,ffff,xx
07,gggg,xx
08,iiii,xx
09,kkkk,xx
10,llll,xx
11,mmmm,xx
12,gerf,xx
13,flrg,xx
14,erge,xx
15,lkro,xx
16,ergf,xx
17,kiwu,xx
18,erjg,xx
19,hytj,xx
20,utkj,xx
21,rger,xx
22,ehth,xx
23,kmik,xx
24,ergb,xx
25,ergk,xx
26,egeg,xx
27,ejer,xx
28,gtrh,xx
29,thrh,xx
30,rhtr,xx
31,gtrh,xx
32,thrh,xx
33,rhtr,xx
```

**uploaded file**

```
cod,char,xx
01,aaaa,xx
02,bbbb,xx
03,cccc,xx
0iiii,xx
09,kkkk,xx
10,llll,xx
11,mmmm,xx
12,gerf,xx
13,flrg,xx
14,erge,xx
15,lkro,xx
16,ergf4,dddd,xx
05,eeee,xx
06,ffff,xx
07,gggg,xx
08,x
21,rger,xx
22,ehth,xx
23,kmik,xx
24,ergb,xx
,xx
17,kiwu,xx
18,erjg,xx
19,hytj,xx
20,utkj,x9,thrh,xx
30,rhtr,xx
31,gtrh,xx
32,thrh,xx
33,rhtr,xx

25,ergk,xx
26,egeg,xx
27,ejer,xx
28,gtrh,xx
2
```

Последний чанк красного цвета потому, что фронт получает респонс от фласки `'Size mismatch', 500` - размер файла после загрузки последнего чанка не совпадает.

У кого есть идеи, как это пофиксить?

Comment: Вопрос перевел, по существу кто-то ответит? )